# git checkout doesn't update file

Tags: git, branching-and-merging

I have two Git branches `master` and `develop`. For various reasons, my `develop` branch got messed up and I'd like to get all the files from `master` to `develop`. I know it's not the right solution, but here's what I did:

```
git checkout master
cd ..
cp repo repo_master
cd repo
git checkout develop
cp -r ../repo_master/* .
```

The weird thing is that, after copying my files (which should be in the `master`'s version) into my repo, running

```
git diff
```

Doesn't show anything. I don't get it. What is even weirder is that running

```
git diff master develop
```

Does show a lot of differences.

What am I doing wrong? Also, how should I do it?

Comment: You need to give us more information here.  _What_ got messed up?  _When_ did it happen, i.e. how many commits ago did it happen?  The typical way to resolve a problem like this doesn't necessarily involve another branch, it just means resetting things back until you reach a stable point.

Comment: Well basically I use git flow and wanted to do a code modernization (it was using Java 5), so I got the **terribly bad idea** to treat this as a feature. When I merged back into `develop`, *something* made that the whole code was doubled (I guess git just estimated that it was the best way to handle the conflicts...) and that's how I got a small hundred classes not to compile anymore. I would have done resets but I was working on a feature branch that got merged (yeah, that was the problem) into `develop` while other changes were made on `develop`.

Comment: So I just thought, given the nature of my modifications, I would rather take back the `master` code - which is working, by definition of git flow - and put it back into `develop` to have a "fresh start"

Comment: Git doesn't work this way.  You don't use move over a bunch of source code like this if the whole branch has a problem.  Instead, just reset your `develop` branch to some commit from `master`.  I can't give an exact answer, because your current state seems to be in a mess.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need to preserve any changes in develop:

`git branch -d develop` will remove develop branch with it's contents.

`git checkout -b develop` will make a copy of current branch (in your case master) to the new branch named develop.

Or if you need anything to preserve in development:

`git checkout develop`

`git merge master --no-ff`
then resolve conflicts, if any.

Comment: Does that also delete all the commits I've made to `develop`?

Comment: Since branch is the set of commits, the answer is yes, it will delete all the commits from specified branch. If you, at any point, merged it with other branches, the code in those branches will stay as it is.

Answer (score 1):

```
git checkout develop
git reset master
```

This will reset your develop branch to match the master branch exactly. All commits specific to the develop branch will be removed.

Answer (score 0):

```
git checkout develop
git checkout master -- .
```

The second command copies all files from branch `master` to the current worktree and index. Verify with `git diff --cached` and commit.

Answer (score 0):

You can undo your merge by using

```
git rebase -i --commiter-date-is-author-date HEAD~50
```

and remove the lines starting from the bottom of the commits list. Up until you reach your last commit before merge. 
save and exit the file.

Check your latest commits again to make sure its OK with

```
git log -n 10 --oneline
```

then finally *override your remote*

```
git push origin -f
```